# How to extend length of the streams in this StreamPlot

Tags: streams

Is it possible the force the streams in StreamPlot[] to extend the full range of the graphic given specific points of my choosing? For example, notice the streams for the following code are short. I would like to streams to extend through the entire graphic.

```
StreamPlot[{1, -2 y}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
 StreamPoints -> {{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}}]
```

[image]

Note, that the bottom stream should be a horizontal line all the way across the graphic through {1,0}.  Any ideas?  I've tried different settings for the StreamScale and StreamPoints options, but can't seem to lengthen the streams.

Comment: try `StreamPlot[{1, -2 y}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, StreamPoints -> {30}]`  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29O1p.png)  or `StreamPlot[{1, -2 y}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, StreamPoints -> {5}]`  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGTHB.png)

Comment: @Nasser  Thank you, however, I need my streams to pass through specific points that I decide.  In the example above I chose {1, 0} and  {1, 1}.  It seems your answer works but you don't get to choose a point the streams pass through.

Comment: For one point, this seems to work `StreamPlot[{1, -2 y}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 StreamPoints -> {{{{1, 0}}, 1}}]`  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pCHj.png)  I admit I find syntax for StrealPoints very hard to understand./

Comment: Yes, certainly not intuitive.

Comment: I think the `SteadmPlot`  can only draw the local line, to draw the global line why not directly use `NDSolve`?